# How to fix java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null error in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a jenkins pipeline job , it was working fine , today it started throwing this error .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicInterpreter.<init>(BasicInterpreter.java:66)
at org.parboiled.transform.RuleMethodInterpreter.<init>(RuleMethodInterpreter.java:42)
at org.parboiled.transform.InstructionGraphCreator.process(InstructionGraphCreator.java:41)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.runMethodTransformers(ParserTransformer.java:62)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:45)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:39)
at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null
at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:58)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:80)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:74)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expand(TokenMacro.java:199)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:237)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:207)
at org.jenkinsci.lib.configprovider.model.ConfigFileManager.provisionConfigFile(ConfigFileManager.java:98)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ManagedFileUtil.provisionConfigFiles(ManagedFileUtil.java:82)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ConfigFileBuildWrapper.setUp(ConfigFileBuildWrapper.java:61)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreWrapperStep$Execution2.doStart(CoreWrapperStep.java:97)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0        (GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:77)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help me to fix the error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the error by downgrading the jenkins deb package to 2.263.4.

```
apt-get install jenkins=2.263.4

systemctl restart jenkins
```

The latest jenkins 2.277.1 seems to have issue with pipeline plugin .

Answer (score 14):

Token Macro plugin needs updating, see: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64555